# Background Image that covers whole webpage, is responsive and also is chosen randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page that has a background image that uses the css cover property so that it is responsive in the browser but doesn't get distorted but is chosen by random from an array in jQuery.

I don't have much code because this is the only thing that I am doing at the moment, I've been playing around but I don't have much of a handle on jQuery so I don't really know what I am doing! Any help appreciated!

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">   
    </div>  
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-image: url(backgroundImage)
}

html, body { 
    overflow: none !important; 
    overflow-x: none !important; 
    overflow-y: none !important; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
var picArr = ['Images/IMG_3764.jpg', 'Images/IMG_3793.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4050.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4323.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4351.jpg', ];

var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("background-image").attr('url', picArr[myNumber]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to randomise it, use a setTimeout()

Also, to change the background image on the "background" div, just .css jquery selector like below.

eg

```
var picArr = ['Images/IMG_3764.jpg', 'Images/IMG_3793.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4050.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4323.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4351.jpg', ];

$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

    $("#background").css('background-image', 'url('+picArr[myNumber]+')'); //here
  }, 3000); // ms of how often you want it to change.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have used this but have just removed the Timeout because I only want it to load something different upon refresh, but otherwise this is perfect! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you misstype the selector `$("background-image")`, isn't this supposed to be `$("#background")`

```js
var picArr = ['Images/IMG_3764.jpg', 'Images/IMG_3793.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4050.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4323.jpg', 'Images/IMG_4351.jpg', ];

var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#background").attr('url', picArr[myNumber]); //here
});
```

```css
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-image: url(backgroundImage)
}
```

```html
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="background">
</div>
```

Comment: Even if I do this, nothing comes up when you run the snippet, or if I load my webpage

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has already been answered now but this was my solution:

```
var picArr = ['http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-1.jpg', 'http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-4.jpg', 'http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-640-480-2.jpg'];

var l = picArr.length;

var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);

console.log(myNumber);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#background").attr('style', 'background: url(' + picArr[myNumber]) + ')';
});
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```